# For Loop to fill a Column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with zero columns and zero rows, and I want to have the `for loop` fill in numbers from 1 to 39. The numbers should be repeating themselves twice until 39, so for instance, the result I am looking for will be in one column, where each number repeats twice

Assume `st` is the data frame I have set already. This is what I have so far:

```
for(i in 1:39) {
  append(st,i) 
  for(i in 1:39) {
    append(st,i)
  }
}
```

Expected outcome will be in a column structure:

```
1
1
2
2
3 
3
.
.
.
.
39
39
```

Comment: Don't use loops. `st$column_name = rep(1:39, each = 2)`. See the help page `?rep` for details.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `for loop`. Instead use `rep()`

```
# How many times you want each number to repeat sequentially
times_repeat <- 2

# Assign the repeated values as a data frame
test_data <-  as.data.frame(rep(1:39, each = times_repeat))

# Change the column name if you want to
names(test_data) <- "Dont_encourage_the_use_of_blanks_in_column_names"
```

Comment: `data.frame(var = rep(1:39, each = times_repeat))` will be more concise.

Comment: You might change the name of the column to something like `Dont_encourage_the_use_of_blanks_in_column_names` ;)

Comment: @markus - Thank you for the useful comment. I have updated the answer.

Comment: You really used that name? (+1)